# Wrapper class object as a return type

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive-types

It's a very simple question which I could not understand. I am still a beginner in Java.

Consider a example:

```
public Integer function() {
    int i=1;
    return i;
}
```

The return type is an `Integer` type and  I am returning a `primitive` type. It is allowed by the compiler.

So the **question** is, how that conversion(primitive to wrapper) takes place.

I am using `JDK 1.7`.

Comment: autoboxing is done during returning the int value

Comment: which version of java r u using? After jdk1.5 autoboxing feature has been introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is known as [Autoboxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Autoboxing). [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) Oracle tutorial should shed some light on the matter.

Comment: Oh yes.. It is `Autoboxing`. I thought `Autoboxing` is only used when `=` operator is used. Now its clear.